loads of random 404s on my site, e.g. /PMG2_00RxzxTHnoN/
Every day we get several hundred 404 errors reported when someone/somebot tries to access seemingly random URLs on our site, eg today we had:

/PMG2_00RxzxTHnoN/
/xcUT0qMO9A2omxN-/
/JfqxLE9JNU1bHkI7/

First I'm wondering if these are harmful in anyway in terms of blocking our site. And second, since they're obviously randomly generated, how can I block them? I'm not even sure how to see where they come from.
Thanks.

Where are these reported? Server logs, Google Search Console, or a third party tool?

Within the REDIRECTION plugin on WP. Every day we got more...
